# JavaScript For-in vs Object.key().forEach what is the difference?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, foreach, for-in-loop

What I wonder though is: using Object.keys() would have a different impact on memory compared to the other looping methods, since it needs to create the "index" array that contains all the object keys first?

Comment: Unless you have millions of properties in your object, I suspect the difference is inconsequential. But if you must, try it yourself to see?

Comment: `for .. in` also iterates over inherited enumerable properties, while `Object.keys()` only iterates over own enumerable properties. And to your concerns about memory footprint: avoid premature optimizations. Use what's more convenient to you.